# How to display only next one week from the current day using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, date

I want to display date in the current format as like the attached image
[image: weekday format]

Comment: Show us what you've tried, by pasting your attempts/code in the question. We can't just pull a solution out of thin air for you. Not without any effort from your end, and some basic markup.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  var wa = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
   $(".date .days").append("<div class='dates' id='day" + i + "'>" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + '<span>' + wa[date.getDay()] +'</span>'+ "</div>");
 }

By using the above code i can able to display the next 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can add some `if` statements, you can help address specific scenarios. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var date;
  var wa = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    var day = $("<div>", {
      class: "dates",
      id: "day-" + i
    }).appendTo($(".date .days"));
    if (i == 0) {
      day.addClass("today");
    }
    var dNum = date.getDate();
    day.html((dNum < 10 ? "0" + dNum : dNum));
    if (i == 0) {
      $("<span>").html("Today").appendTo(day);
    } else if (i == 1) {
      $("<span>").html("Tom").appendTo(day);
    } else {
      $("<span>").html(wa[date.getDay()]).appendTo(day);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.days {
  border: #eee;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.dates {
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dates span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.today {
  background: #F66;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">
  <div class="days"></div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.